# Why does character() creates integer columns in my df?

Tags: r, dataframe

As explained in [R Documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/character.html), `character()` creates character objects of specified length.
For example :

```
ex.vect<-character(5)
typeof(ex.vect)
length(ex.vect)
```

> [1] "character"
>
> [1] 5

But if I use the exact same code to create character columns in a data frame, the columns turn out to be integers :

```
ex.df<-data.frame(col1=character(5),col2=character(5))
typeof(ex.df$col1)
```

> [1] "integer"

The issue can be fixed this way :

```
ex.df$col1<-as.character(ex.df$col1)
typeof(ex.df$col1)
```

> [1] "character"

But it is pretty ungraceful, and not convenient at all if a lot of columns have to be converted.

So, I have two questions :

**1. Why does `integer()` creates integer columns when used inside
    `data.frame()` ?**

**2. Is there better ways to create a data frame with empty character columns ?**

Comment: by default, `data.frame` converts characters to `factor` objects.  Factors are internally represented as integers.  Try using `data.frame(..., stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: @Benjamin Nice, thank you ! Do you know why such a conversion is made by default ? I guess there are good reasons but that's rather disturbing to me...

Comment: @Vincent in short, it was because character strings used a lot of memory, and memory used to be expensive.  See https://simplystatistics.org/2015/07/24/stringsasfactors-an-unauthorized-biography/ if you want a detailed history.

Comment: @Benjamin That makes sense indeed. Again, thank you very much !

Comment: use `sapply(ex.df,as.character)` to turn all into character. The reason as to why it turns it to integer I believe has been comprehensively answered.